# Is it legal to inject javascript to the netflix website and publish it?

Tags: website

I want to publish a javascript code which changes the way www.netflix.com behaves. One thing this script does is change the language.

Am I also allowed to publish a chrome extension with the name "netflix... language changer ..." or am i misleading people to think that i am a part of netflix?

This might be seen as a trademark abuse.

Comment: It seems you are asking different questions: You publishing some JavaScript that someone else could potentially download and install into their browser to modify how a web site operates is one thing, an end user downloading and using that to modify how that web site operates is another, and you publishing software for download with the word 'netflix' in the name of the software package is another.

Comment: Almost everything (anything) you do on the client side is legal, unless it's breaking copyright laws of course.

Comment: @nucn43za No, it is three questions. No cake, but you should make them separate questions if you want separate answers. They are three different things after all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does a client-side Javascript injection into a page of Netflix you have downloaded and is it an offence under the Computer Misuse Act 1990? No. Is it against copyright laws? No. What about trademark abuse? It's possible.

First of all, only Netflix can tell you this with their terms of service. Do they allow you to distribute scripts that may affect the way others with the extension see the page? You see, anything you do on the client side is alright.

AFAIK there has been no court case on it but that doesn't mean it's legal. With a little bit of sense, you should understand that as long as you say you're not affiliated with Netflix, it works.

Comment: That's the answer i wanted to hear. Thank you very much.

Comment: @nucn43za depending on what the script does, though, the answer could change, for example if it violates the terms of service apart from any terms governing the injection itself.  In other words, even if it is okay to do this with a script that changes the language of some page elements, it might still be forbidden to do it with a script that does something else, for example, by modifying the media stream.

Comment: Be wary when you get the answer you want to hear, especially when it doesn't analyze any law. I can't say whether your proposed course of action is legal or not, but just saying you're not affiliated with Netflix doesn't sound like a great way to immunize your use of their trademark.